# Getting 404 not found message when I try to run this import json file app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use this "import json" code to try and understand something better but it cannot find my data.json file when I run it locally. Where should I place my data.json file? I have my main directory where index.html resides and I have an app directory for my js files. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="app/services.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <code>
      {{name}}
    </code>
    <hr />
    <code>
      {{children | json}}
    </code>
    <hr />
    <h2>children</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="child in children">
      {{child.data}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['jsonService']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, JsonService) {
  JsonService.get(function(data){
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.children = data.children;
  });
});
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
.factory('JsonService', function($resource) {
  return $resource('data.json');
});
```

Comment: why are you putting in a `base` url tag?

Comment: you need to use http:// service or local server otherwise you cannot use http request. 

And your question;
$resource('..or/../somefolder/data.json');

Comment: OK, here is the weird thing. I changed the name of my data file from data.json to data.txt then anything in the code that referred to data.json I changed to data.txt and now everything works??